# Pandas merge two DF with rows replacement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aws-data-wrangler

I faced with an issue to merge two DF into one and save all duplicate rows by `id` value from the second DF. Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'],
    'com': [134.6, 223, 0, 123],
    'malicious': [False, False, True, False]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['id7', 'id2', 'id5', 'id6'],
    'com': [134.6, 27.6, 0, 123],
    'malicious': [False, False, False, False]
})

df1
    id    com  malicious
0  id1  134.6      False
1  id2  223.0      False
2  id3    0.0       True
3  id4  123.0      False

df2
    id    com  malicious        date
0  id7  134.6      False  2021-01-01
1  id2   27.6      False  2021-01-01
2  id5    0.0      False  2021-01-01
3  id6  123.0      False  2021-01-01
```

I'm. expecting the output to be:

```
    id    com  malicious        date
1  id1  134.6      False  null
2  id3    0.0       True  null
3  id4  123.0      False  null
4  id7  134.6      False  2021-01-01
5  id2   27.6      False  2021-01-01
6  id5    0.0      False  2021-01-01
7  id6  123.0      False  2021-01-01
```

As you can see we added a new column and all rows of df1 a null there now and row with `id2` is replaced with all values from `df2`(amount of updated columns can be different, so it's not about updating specific columns values, but about replacing the whole row by `id`)
I dont care about indexes and sort

Looking for efficient solution as I have huge amount of files, which I should merge this way into main DF

Comment: There is added `Date` column? Because `df2` in DataFrame looks different like output of df2 in sample data

Comment: @jezrael yes. Columns can differ, but dtype of all columns are stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need unique `id` with remove values from `df1` if exist also in `df2` use:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

Comment: Looks like it what I need, thanks. Will test it and update you if works fine